# Is stack a logical memory area in heap?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, heap-memory, stack-memory

In Java, objects are stored in the heap but method local variables are in the stack. But when I open jconsole, I do not see any memory allocated in the stack. I just see heap and permgen (Java 6). Is the stack just a logical separation in the heap and not physical?

Comment: See [Is frame in JVM heap allocated or stack allocated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741925/is-frame-in-jvm-heap-allocated-or-stack-allocated/26779782#26779782) and [How do I get stack memory stats programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835087/how-do-i-get-stack-memory-stats-programatically/26852490#26852490)

Comment: BTW I suggest you migrate from Java 6 to 8 and `jconsole` to `jmc` as soon as possible.

Comment: The fact that `jconsole` doesn’t show this information doesn’t allow any conclusion about the organization of the stack.

Comment: Stack and Heap are just memory that happen to be used as stacks and heaps. They are allocated in the same way from the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM uses the native stack of the process. This minimise overhead, and allows the stack to be virtual (it can have a maximum size much larger than what is actually used)

As a result most stacks are rarely used much ( << 10% of maximum ) and graphing them might be more confusing than useful.

Comment: `The JVM uses the native stack of the process.` I believe it means memory allocated for process by OS. Then it must be separate from heap mentioned through -Xms and -Xmx parameters. ?

Comment: @emilly only virtual memory/address space is allocated. When this happens only the pages touched turn into real memory.i.e if you set the maximum to 10 MB, but you use only 21 KB, then 6 * 4 KB is actually used (24 KB) You can set the maximum size for a stack with `-Xss` though this is rarely needed.

Comment: sorry. say I have total ram of 4 GB. I have allocated 1GB max memory for heap. Now stack for some reason needs 512M memory then it will be allocated out of 3GB ( 4-1) ?

Comment: @emilly each thread has it's own stack. I would leave it with the default setting unless you know it's a problem.

Comment: I am not facing any issue right now and not going to change any default setting . But want wan to understand whether memory for stack region is allocated out of heap or it allocated from rest of the RAM ?

Comment: @emilly the stack, direct memory, shared libraries, GUI components, PermGen/metastases,  memory mapped files use native memory rather than the heap.

Answer (score 1):

No. Stack is a different area of memory dedicated to holding information related to method calls, such as argument values and where program flow should return after the method returns.

Comment: then why stack area memory analysis is not displayed in any memory analyzer tool like jconsole etc

Comment: @emilly the size of the stack is rarely a problem, what would the tool show?

Comment: The stack changes with every method call and return. What would you have the analyzer tool report?